# Can exploding ammo crates cause damage?

Tags: battlefield-3

It was suggested to me by a friend that I shouldn't put an ammo crate down next to my mortar as it would cause damage if it was destroyed by enemy fire. Personally, I doubt that destroying one of these crates actually causes damage, but I honestly don't know for certain. I know that they can, in fact, be destroyed by enemy damage, which causes them to "explode" (for lack of a better term). When this happens, do they cause any amount of damage?

Comment: If destroying an mcom station doesn't do anything,  this certainly won't.

Comment: why don't you test this hypothesis? http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/12/dont-be-afraid-to-use-the-science/

Comment: @JeffAtwood if I get the chance I'll try and put this to the test but I've been pretty busy lately

Comment: Ammo and health crates will "explode" if an enemy throws a grenade or some other explosive lands near it. But the question of whether it causes damage is certainly interesting. I personally don't think that it does...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was reading bf3blog.com and official DICE press releases for like half a year, as well as battlefield.wikia.com and some twitter feeds of their devs, plus I spent approximately 100 hours in multiplayer, and I have never seen/heard about ammo boxes causing any damage to anything.

*I would post this as a comment, but sorry, not "mature" enough.*

Comment: Yeah, I really doubt they do any damage but I figured I'd put it out there in case anybody else knew for sure

Comment: I have *never* seen an ammo-crate explode in >100 hours of play. He probably was hit by a mortar-strike once, and mis-interpreted it.

Comment: they explode all the time (or at any rate are destroyed by damage)

Comment: No they don't. I've tried it out myself back in 2012. Not sure if it still is now that its 2013, but it didn't cause any damage back then.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm in the 200+ hours I've played as support I have never been hurt by an exploding ammo crate. The official BF3 Wiki has no mention of damage as well.